# Piggy-backing on the adjacent romex question ... through wall to rear of surface-mounted receptacle box?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Is it possible to run romex from an unfinished space where back-side of drywall and framing are exposed, through the wall to a finished space, and surface-mount a receptacle box?  How about MC?  Or EMT?  And where is this in the NEC?  Thank you!  Rich

Comment: What is said unfinished space used for? Storage? Equipment? Vehicles? Shop space?

Comment: It’s a storage space in the basement of a home. Thank you, Rich